# Kubernetes Service running on Azure with Public-IP. What is the DNS Name?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, load-balancing

I have a kubernetes service running on Azure. After the deployment and service are created, the service publishes an External-IP address and I am able to access the service on that IP:Port.

However, I want to access the service through a regular domain name. I know that the kubernetes cluster running on Azure has its own DNS, but how can I figure out what the service DNS name is???

I am running multiple services, and they refer to one another using the <_ServiceName>.<_Namespace>.svc.cluster.local naming convention, but if I attempt to access the Service using <_ServiceName>.<_Namespace>.svc.<_kubernetesDNS>.<_location>.azureapp.com, it doesnt work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The decision will be how you want to expose the service: through [`LoadBalancer`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer) or through a [`NodePort`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport). When you run on Azure, `LoadBalancer` means that you will get a public IP from Azure that does not have an FQDN (fully-qualified domain name) associated. If you choose `NodePort`, then your service will be exposed on a port of your nodes, and you can access it through the agen-fqdn:port.  Hope this helps!

Comment: If you own a domain, then you can associate  a CNAME to the public IP of your service. Please let me know if you need additional information on any of this, glad to expand on them. Good luck!

Comment: Hi radu-matei, So, I really appreciate your help. I saw that I can expose a NodePort, but since I'm running a cluster, I'd prefer not to have to hit a specific node. CNAME to the public IP! That's the one. I will look into it, but if you have additional information, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

In Azure, you can use the "Public IP addresses" resource and associate public Ip that is being used by your service, to a DNS name under the default Azure DNS Namespace : `.location.couldapp.azure.com`.
eg: `demo.k8s.service.centralindia.couldapp.azure.com`

Note: The Dns record should be unique.

Else try creating Azure DNS to create your own domain.

[image: associating a public Ip to default dns record provided by azure]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in order to use DNS you should have Service type LoadBalancer. It will create ExternalIp for your service. So if you have and Service which type is LoadBalancer you may  take your external IP address of service with below command:

```
kubectl get services --all-namespaces
```

Then copy external ip and give below commands via PowerShell

P.S change IP adress with your own external ip address and service name with your own service name

```
$IP="23.101.60.87"
$DNSNAME="yourservicename-aks"
$PUBLICIPID=az network public-ip list --query "[?ipAddress!=null]|[?contains(ipAddress, '$IP')].[id]" --output tsv
az network public-ip update --ids $PUBLICIPID --dns-name $DNSNAME
```

So after this commands just give command below via PowerShell again, it will show you your DNS:

```
az network public-ip list --query "[?ipAddress!=null]|[?contains(ipAddress, '$IP')].[dnsSettings.fqdn]" -o table
```

Reference: http://alakbarv.azurewebsites.net/2019/01/25/azure-kubernetes-service-aks-get-dns-of-your-service/

Answer (score -1):

Expose the service as 'Load Balancer' type and it will automatically create an Azure Load Balancer, with a Public IP. An Azure Public IP also have a domain name you can use under the azure.com domain.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm

Comment: Yes, exposing the service as a Load Balancer automatically creates an Load Balander and a public IP in Azure. But can we specify a value for the domain of the auto generated public IP ?

Comment: no. but you can create a DNS (typically CNAME) to point your domain to the Azure provided domain.

Comment: It is that I did. But my question was not that; it is  : can we provide the Azure domain of the IP automatically created by the kubernetes load balancer service ? By default, the IP is created with no Azure domain.

Comment: @gentiane I'm not sure I understand your question, by maybe your are looking for something like https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns